# Java, buffer lazily allocated, free-able on demand and addressed as byte []

Tags: java, memory-management

I am trying to implement a proof-of-concept memory-aware scheduling functionality by extending an existing Java program. The program uses buffers under the form of `byte []`. For my purpose `byte []` are problematic because

1. they are garbage collected
2. they are allocated upfront instead of lazily (the JVM seems to touch all pages it has allocated when creating the buffer)
3. they make the JVM allocate more and more memory which is not given back the OS.

To achieve my goal I would like buffers to be lazily allocated memory (pages allocated only when written to) and free-able on demand. This is similar to how it would happen in C++.
In addition, as much as possible, I would like to minimize the changes to the existing code-base.

I looked at `nio.ByteBuffer` and at the Unsafe classes. Neither fits my case because

1. `java.nio.ByteBuffers` don't seem to be lazily allocated. When I allocate an empty 1GB buffer the RSS of the program immediately goes to 1GB.
2. `Unsafe.allocateMemory` is lazily allocated but I do not know how to reference it as `byte []`.

Is there any way to solve this? 
Any way to view memory allocated with `Unsafe.allocateMemory()` as a `byte []`?
Or change an existing `byte []` to point to memory allocated with Unsafe?

Thank you

Comment: I just don't see how that "would happen in C++". You are generally describing how the low-level virtual memory-to-RAM commitment works, but that's as true of Java as of C++. The only difference is that C++ doesn't automatically initialize everything to zero, which allows the pages to stay uncommitted. They are still allocated, though.

Comment: So what you are after is a way to allocate memory in Java without initializing it.

Comment: I totally agree with you. For me the advantage of the C++ behaviour seems to be that it allows overcommit-ing of memory. I can allocate a large buffer and if I only use a bit of it that is ok, no harm done. With the Java approach that eats up memory that could be used by other processes.

Comment: Yes, allocating without initializing is part of it. But I would also like it to be outside of the garbage collector reach. And to be able to access it as a byte [] so that I do not have to change existing code. Sounds tough to do :(

Comment: `Unsafe#allocateMemory` fits your bill up to becoming a `byte[]`, which would breach the JLS and thus isn't a realistic option. I guess the closest you may get is to build a byte-oriented abstraction around it and adapt existing code.

Comment: That is one option but the existing code-base is not very well written and passes byte [] among many classes. It will be quite time-consuming. I am hoping for some magic (reflection?) that would allow perhaps modifying an existing byte [] to point to some memory allocated with Unsafe.allocateMemory.

Comment: But realize that a `byte[]` is nothing close to a homogenous chunk of address space. It has headers, type information, length field, GC flags, etc. It is designed to play along with the JVM band.

Comment: Exactly. That is why, at least for me, it seems very hard to do.

Comment: "Impossible" is more appropriate, save for forking the entire OpenJDK project and fixing up HotSpot to treat this.

Answer (score 0):

Java is designed to have seperate regions of memory.

- on heap like byte[] which is designed to be re-allocable and is zero'ed out and not lazy.  The reason this is so is that the memory is managed.
- off heap which has the advantage it can be lazy but it can't pretend to be managed data types like byte[].